# Why this customizing of Yii validate message didn't work?

Tags: validation, yii

It's didn't work

```
array('fio', 'length', 'min'=>5, 'max'=>30, 'message' => 'custom'),
```

but this work

```
array('fio, login, password', 'required', 'message' => '{attribute} custom'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `CStringValidator`, there is another [property called `is`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CStringValidator#is-detail) which specifies the exact length of a string, and the `message` property is used only when `is` property is not satisfied by the input.

Take a look at [the source](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.12/framework/validators/CStringValidator.php#L99), and this will become clear:

```php
if($this->is!==null && $length!==$this->is)
{
    $message=$this->message!==null?$this->message:Yii::t('yii','{attribute} is of the wrong length (should be {length} characters).');
    $this->addError($object,$attribute,$message,array('{length}'=>$this->is));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this type of validators:

> In addition to the {@link message} property for setting a custom error
>   message,  * CStringValidator has a couple custom error messages you
>   can set that correspond to different  * validation scenarios. For
>   defining a custom message when the string is too short,   * you may
>   use the {@link tooShort} property. Similarly with {@link tooLong}. The
>   messages may contain   * placeholders that will be replaced with the
>   actual content. In addition to the "{attribute}"   * placeholder,
>   recognized by all validators (see {@link CValidator}),
>   CStringValidator allows for the following  * placeholders to be
>   specified: